# data-reveal loading partial view MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have the following code on my cshtml page:

```
<div class="large reveal" id="draftProductModal" data-reveal>
                        <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
                            <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="input-group-field" id="draftSearchProducts" name="draftSearchProducts" placeholder="SearchProducts" />
                        <div class="input-group-button">
                            <!--Add product to order lines button-->
                            <a id="draftAddProduct" class="hollow button secondary" data-open="draftProductModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Search Products</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I need to take the value in the draftSearchProducts text field, pass it to a controller that returns a partialview:

```
public ActionResult SearchResults(string keywords, int queryLimit = 20, int offset = 0)
    {
        try
        {
           //connect to db, grab data return results
            searchResults.ProductDetails = products.ToList();

            return PartialView("_SearchResults", searchResults);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I need to send in the keyword to the controller, return the partial view and load it into the draftProductModal div and display the div. How is this done?  I am new to front end development.

Tried this code:

```
 var url = '/ProductsController/SearchResults';
$('#draftAddProduct').click(function () {
    var keyWord = $('draftSearchProducts').val();
    $('#draftProductModal').load(url, { keywords: keyWord });

});
```

And all I get is a 404 error, so it appears I am not hitting my controller.  I think I am getting close, I just need to find out how to access the controller ActionResult.  Still accepting help.

Comment: " I am new to front end development " when I want to learn something I usually try to learn by doing a tutorial e.g. : http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/partial-view-in-asp.net-mvc worth your time if you think you will be doing this more than once

Comment: I'll give it a go.  Thanks.

Comment: looks like your making good progress. if you have issues you can tag me (@DaniDev) and I'll try to help.

Comment: Found the problem.  Looks like I was using the wrong controller name. Here  is the code:

 $('#draftAddProduct').click(function () {
        var keyWord = $('#draftProductModal').val();
        $('#draftProductModal').load("@Url.Action("SearchResults","Products")?keywords=chair");
    });

Comment: Nice work figuring it out! I could have told you (answered), but then you would not have learned everything else you have undoubtedly learned along the way :-)